# Integration of Bootstrap 4 Carousel in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently developing a theme for my blog, I have a question about the integration of Carousel Slider in Wordpress.

The slider works pretty well, showing the latest 5 posts with a featured image and a caption with the title of the post. However i've had to set a fixed height to the img, cause different size of images would change constantly the height of the carousel, so the result was not pretty good.

The problem is that on mobile the img stretch a lot, so i would like to set the post thumbnail as a background of the carousel, so i can set bg-size, bg-position etc. in order to achieve a perfectly responsive image.

Do you know if there is a way to reach that? Or maybe it is possible with my actual code without setting the thumbnail as a bg?

Thank you all in advance.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
           <?php $active_class = ( 0 === $the_query->current_post ) ? ' active': ''; ?>
                <div class="carousel-item <?php echo esc_attr( $active_class ); ?>">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full') ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register a new image for your carousel using `add_image_size( 'home-carousel', <width here>, <height here>, false );`.

Then, you can call the_post_thumbnail('full') like this- `the_post_thumbnail('home-carousel')`. If you have already uploaded the images, you need to regenerate the thumbnails using this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).

If you still want to go with the background image option - you can get the URL of the featured image by this function - [get_the_post_thumbnail_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) and set it as background for the .carousel-item div.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going with the background image option, seems to be more responsive for my purpose.. but, how can I add the permalink? I mean, with the 'old' code that you can see in the first post, when I click on the thumbnail, the carousel redirect me to the post itself.. but obviously, with the background option this doesn't work.. Maybe it is stupid and easy, but i'm stuck right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is my actual code using the thumbnail as a background-image.. but, like i said, the permalink doesn't work. Is there a way to have it work also with the thumbnail as a background? If I'm not clear, i want that when the user clicks on the image, it redirect to the single page post.

```
<div class="carousel-item <?php echo esc_attr( $active_class ); ?>" style="background:url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full');?>') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover; min-height: 75vh;">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just replace div.carousel-item with a.carousel-item and add a href attribute. Also, remove the empty link inside carousel item. This should work.